# xnormal weird normal map bake, substance and handplane baked flawlessly

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map, artifacts

[image]

can someone possibly explain why this is happening, this was from a model I baked in XNormal, I don't really understand why its having this effect. I tested bakes in Substance and HandPlane; both gave me okay results. While XNormal gave me this. If only I knew what caused this it'd be easier to fix.

I recently found a forum post about it, but no real answers were given.

I checked my smoothing groups and my cage; it was perfect or okay. Given that it baked perfectly in Substance and HandPlane It should of worked in XNormal. Previously a similar effect appeared in substance yet XNormal baked it perfectly.

The effect is random to me and I have no Idea what causes it. Could any of you shed some light on this?

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that .OBJ have less problems than .FBX when it came to XNormal bakes, so I opted out for OBJ to FBX convertion on final output.

Answer (score 0):

In Xnormals for the Low poly select average normals, also when importing mesh into engine recalculate normals.. this will fix your problem.
Still got to figure out how to export clean normals with blender fbx :D